# action after sign in with google account

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new in google app engine, so my question may be kind of stupid or trivial, but anyway... For each user (for each google acc) I have an entity in my datastore. So when a new user logs in I want to add him to database.
I use:

```
- url: /.*
  login: required
```

To make sure user is logged in with his google acc. The problem is when someone signs in from a subpage (blabla.appspot.com/something) then after log in he will be redirected to blabla.appspot.com/something and I have to verify in Request handler for "something" if the current user is already stored in database. How to do it without adding the same code to each request handler? Maybe it's possible to redirect to the main page after log in or something similar?

Comment: Maybe post some code with this? Your looking at writing a decorator.

Comment: Ask yourself this: how many websites have you ever visited that immediately send you to a login page rather than displaying some introductory page with a login link/form? Using login: required for all URLs in a webapp is probably a Bad Idea unless you're doing some kind of intranet thing. Logging in via a link also makes the redirection to a registration page a bit less ugly; it eliminates the need to decorate every handler in the app with registration logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach: If you create a subclass of `webapp.RequestHandler` that your handlers will then subclass, you can provide it with a convenience method for getting or creating a `UserInfo` object given `users.get_current_user().user_id()` (or `.user_email()`, if that's what you prefer to use as a key). Your handlers then call the convenience method in their `get()` and `post()` methods.

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def setup_user_info(self):
    # left as an exercise
    self.user_info = user_info
```

and then

```
class MyHandler(MyRequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.setup_user_info()
    ...
```

Comment: Even better, put the call to `setup_user_info` in `initialize`, after calling `super(MyRequestHandler, self).initialize(request, response)`. Or, just have the getter that returns the current user do the initialization.